# How to access match outside of Route?

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

What is the best way to accomplish what I am trying in the code below? App cannot access match.params for routes defined inside it, but I would like to pass parts of the state to child components based on the url params. I cannot use hooks like useRouteMatch() because App is a stateful class component. I think I can do this with the the Route render method, but it looks like React Router docs say that method is deprecated.

So is there a design pattern similar to this that lets me keep all route logic in App and just pass props to child components based on params, that doesnt use the render method of Route?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { things: this.props.things };
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/thing/:thingId'>
          <OneThing thing={this.state.things.find(thing => thing.id === match.params.thingId)} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/things/:thingTag'>
          <MultipleThings things={this.state.things.filter(thing => thing.tag === match.params.thingTag)} />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `<Route render>`

```
    <Route path='/thing/:thingId' 
        render={(route) => <OneThing thing={route.match.params.thingId}  />} />
```

with `<Route children>` ver 5.1

```
<Route
       path='/thing/:thingId'
      children={({ match }) => (
        <OneThing thing={match.params.thingId}  />
      )}
    />
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but I'm also wondering if there is a way to do this without the render method.

Comment: Where did you find render method deprecated, I couldn't find?

Comment: "Although they are not deprecated in 5.1, the <Route component> and <Route render> APIs have several quirks that just aren't needed (see the discussion in useParams above) in a world with hooks. We will most likely deprecate these APIs in a future release." From:
https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/

Comment: I've updated my answer with version 5.1, please have a look

Comment: Awesome! You da bomb!

Answer (score 0):

try using [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter)

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

// A simple component that shows the pathname of the current location
class OneThing extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    match: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    location: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    history: PropTypes.object.isRequired
  };

  render() {
    const { match, location, history } = this.props;

    return <div>You are now at {location.pathname}</div>;
  }
}

// Create a new component that is "connected" (to borrow redux
// terminology) to the router.
export default withRouter(ShowTheLocation);
```